# Python Tuple Comparison not working for multiple less than, more than

Tags: python, comparison, tuples

I have a 3D coordinate tuple (x, y, z). I want to test that none of the 3 co-ords of a given tuple are below (a, b, c) and none are higher than (d, e, f).
Through trial, error, and reading these forums I've learned that:

(a, b, c) <= (x, y, z) <= (d, e, f)

doesn't work as the first expression evaluates, then gets that outcome (0 or 1) and uses it in the next evaluation, and so on.
So now I tried:

((a, b, c) <= (x, y, z)) and ((x, y, z) <= (d, e, f))

This doesn't work either because when it hits a True in any of the three paired comparisons (a, x; b, y; c, z; etc), it results in True. As such, tuple comparisons work more like decimal values rather than three separate scalar variables. I need any failure of all three pair-comparisons (six in total) to produce a False result rather than any success to produce a True.

I hoped for a method as sweetly simple as a <= b <= c.
What is a simple method of doing this with tuples that only produces True when all pair-wise comparisons pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `lower` and `upper` bound as well as your point are three-tuples, try this:

```
lower = 1,2,3
upper = 5,2,7
xyz = 2,3,4

all(u <= j <= v for u, j, v in zip(lower, xyz, upper))
```

Or just compare them individually:

```
(a <= x <= d) and (b <= y <= e) and (c <= z <= f)
```

Comment: I want to say both you and falsetru gave the best answers. After mulling over falsetru's response, I was coming to the pythonic method that you came up with, Tobias. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 3):

According to [`Expression - Comparison`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Tuples and lists are compared **lexicographically** using comparison of corresponding elements. ...

Define your own comparison function.

```
>>> def lte(x, y):
...     return all(a <= b for a, b in zip(x, y))
... 
>>> lte((1,2,3), (2,3,4))
True
>>> lte((1,2,3), (0,3,4))
False
>>> lte((1,2,3), (2,3,4)) and lte((2,3,4), (3,4,5))
True
>>> lte((1,2,3), (2,3,4)) and lte((2,3,4), (3,2,5))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

> Through trial, error, and reading these forums I've learned that [...] doesn't work...

Except that it does, since Python chains relational operators.

```
>>> 3 < 4 < 5
True
>>> 5 > 4 > 3
True
```

> This doesn't work either because when it hits a True in any of the three paired comparisons [...], it results in True.

Except that Python compares *all* elements in both sequence operands (of the same type).

```
>>> (1, 2, 3) >= (1, 2, 4)
False
```

**Please verify that you are in fact using Python, since both of your observations are false in it.**

Comment: When I do print (35, 43, 29) <= (40 , 40, 40), I get True. The answer I want my testing to give me is False, as the 43 is not less than or equal to 40. Do you get something different, or do I have my less thans and greater thans mixed up again? :)

Comment: Then you need to specify that in the question.

Comment: If a<x, (a,b,c)<=(x,y,z) never checks the remaining values, as falsetru noted. OP did specify: when all pair-wise comparisons pass.